# Do we need to make code changes, if we are upgrading node-oracledb from version 5.0.1 to 5.2.0?

Tags: node.js, oracle, oracle11g, node-oracledb

I have a oracle code, which was written when the version of node-oracleDB was 5.0.1. Do I need to make any code changes, if we upgrade to version 5.2.0?

Comment: Check the migration documentation https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#migratev51v52 and the changelog https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible for anyone other than you or your team to answer that as we have no idea what your code looks like. Have you looked at the release notes between those versions to see what has changed?

The only way to be sure no changes are needed are to just test your application on the new version.